# Комиссия в составе

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте". У меня на работе возник вопрос: какая или какие из приведенных фраз являются правильными : "Комиссия в составе начальника участка..., мастера участка..." или "Комиссия в составе: начальник участка..., мастер участка..." или "Комиссия в составе: начальника участка..., мастера участка..." или "Комиссия в составе начальник участка..., мастер участка..."? Помогите, пожалуйста, решить этот вопрос:)) Спасибо:))

Answer (score 1):

Правильными являются фразы: "Комиссия в составе начальника участка..., мастера участка..." или "Комиссия в составе: начальник участка..., мастер участка..." .